# Handle duplicates in batch POST requests to a REST API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, concurrency

### The stack

- Express.js API server for CRUD operations over data.
- MongoDB database.
- Moongose interface for MongoDB for schemas.

### The probem

In order to handle duplicates in just one point, I want to do it in the only possible entry point: The API.

> > **Definition: duplicate**
>
> A duplicate is an entity which already exists in the data base, so the
>   new POST request is the same entity with exact the same data, or it is
>   the same entity with updated data.

The API design is meant to handle the new http2 protocol.

Bulk importers have been written. This programs get the data from a given source, transform the data to our specific format, and make POST request to save it. This importers are designed to handle every entity in parallel.

The API already has a duplication handler which works great when a given entity already exists in the database. The problem comes when the bulk importers make several POST requests for the same entity at the same time, and the entity doesn't exist in the database yet.

```
....POST/1 .databaseCheck.......DataBaseResult=false..........DatabaseWrite
......POST/2 .databaseCheck.......DataBaseResult=false..........DatabaseWrite
........POST/3 .databaseCheck.......DataBaseResult=false..........DatabaseWrite
.....................POST/N .databaseCheck.......DataBaseResult=false..........DatabaseWrite
```

This situation produces the creation of the same entity several times, because the database checks haven't finished when the rest of the POST requests arrive.
Only if the number of POST requests is big enough, the first write operation would have already finished, and the databaseCheck of the Nth request will return true.

What would be the correct solution for handle this?
If I'm not wrong, what I'm looking for has the name of transaction, and I don't know if this is something that the database should offer by default, or if it is something that I have to implement.

Solutions I have already considered:

**1. Limit the requests, just one each time.**

This is the simplest solution, but if the API remains blocked when the bulk importers make several requests, then the frontend client would get very slow, and it is meant to be fast, and multiplayer. So this, in fact, is not a solution.

**2. Special bulk API endpoint for each entity.**

If an application needs to make bulk requests, then make just one huge POST request with all the data as body request.
This solution doesn't block the API, and can handle duplicates very well, but what I don't like is that I would go against the http2 protocol, where many and small request are desired.

And the problem persists and other future clients may have this problem if they don't notice that there is available a bulk endpoint. But maybe this is not a problem.

**3. Try to use the possible MongoDB transaction implementation**

I've read a little bit about this, but I don't know if it would be possible to handle this problem with the MongoDB and Mongoose tools. I've done some search, but I haven't find anything, because before to try to insert many documents, I need to generate the data for each document, and that data is coming inside each POST request.

**4. Drop MongoDB and use a transaction friendly database.**

This would have a big cost at this point because the whole stack is already finished, and we are near to launch. We aren't afraid of refactor. But I think here would apply the 3rd solution considerations.

**5. Own transactions implementation at the API level?**

I've designed a solution that may work for every cases, and that I call the *pool stream.*

This is the design:
When a POST request arrives, a timer of a fixed amount of milliseconds starts. That amount of time would be big enough to catch several requests, and small enough in order to do not cause a noticeable delay.

Inside each chunk of requests, the data is processed trying to merge duplicates before writing in the database. So if inside a chunk n requests have been catch, n - m (where m <= n) unique candidates are generated. A hash function is applied to each candidate in order to assign the hash result to each request-response pair. Then the write operation to the database of the candidates is done in parallel, and the current duplicates handler would work for this at the write time.

When the writes for the current chunk finish, the response is sent to each request-response pair of the chunk, then the next chunk is processed. While a chunk is in the queue waiting for the write operation, could be doing the unique candidates process, in order to accelerate the whole process.

What do you think?
Thank you.